# Measuring Download speed with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

A couple of days ago i've got suggested this code for measuring download speed. However I don't quite understand what is required in URL & outputfile for the code to work. Can someone explain to me? I only have a very basic level of understanding of java. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Speed {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public double getSpeed() throws IOException{
        URL website = new URL("https://www.youtube.com/"); //The source website
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        File outputFile = new File("output.jpg"); //The output file
        outputFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime(); //Measure when you start to download the file, we know that the time it takes to download a file is endTime-startTime
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

        long endTime = System.nanoTime(); //Measure when we're done downloading the file
        long fileBytes = outputFile.length();
        double downloadTimeSeconds = ((double)(endTime-startTime))/1000000000; //1 billion nanoseconds in a second
        double bytesPerSecond = ((double)fileBytes)/downloadTimeSeconds;
        return bytesPerSecond;          
    }
}
```

I have tested the code with download.html as file output & http://www.thinkbroadband.com/download.html as the URL. However it is just returning values between 3KB - 300KB regardless if I am downloading a file or not...

Comment: Which part of the code don't you understand?

Comment: Download of **what** are you supposed to measure?

Comment: Why not try reading the documentation? Your question (_what is required...to work_) suggests you had problems when you tried it. Did you? Which?

Answer (score 1):

**URL** -> The page on web which you want to download

**Output file** -> Where it will be downloaded. As per code it will be created in your project folder. Don't know why they named like .jpg. You can name it anything.. open that file you will lot of html which got downloaded.

**What it returns** -> As per name of that variable and obviously according to logic, it is **"bytes downloaded per second"**

Comment: What do you mean by "open that file you will lot of html which got downloaded."?

Comment: Name that file with extension as txt. Then open that output file (which will be created once you run the program) in some text editor like notepad. You will see html code of the webpage of which you used the url in your program.